# Inserting values into array without indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to parse some `.out` files to get a value `E` contained within each file, and then plot these value against `theta` and `r` as a 3d surface plot. The values of `theta` and `r` are contained in the `.out` file title names: `H2O.r{}theta{}.out`. I.e. r is given in the first `{}` and `theta` is then given in the next `{}`. `r` is given to 2 d.p and `theta` is given to 1 d.p. in the file names, e.g. `r = 0.90, theta = 190.0`.

I am having a hard time iterating through the files, and extracting this information into an `array E` . I have come across an error:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

However, if I change my `r` array to `int` to get rid of this error, then all of the values in `r` will become `0`. Addtionally, my code to extract `E` from the file will no longer work as I will inputting `'H2O.r0.00theta70.out'`, a file which doesn't exist. Does anybody have any suggestions ?

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/myName/ex2/all')

theta = arange(70.0, 161.0, 1, dtype = float)
r = arange(0.70, 1.95, 0.05, dtype = float)
r_2dp = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in r_O ] # string array, with rounding to match the file names
E = zeros((theta.shape[0],r.shape[0]))

def extract(filename):    #extract value from file
        filename = open(filename,"r")
        for line in filename:
            if 'SCF Done' in line:
                l = line.split()
                p = float(l[4])
        return p

for i in r_2dp:    #create E array that will allow me to plot E vs r vs theta
    for j in theta:
        for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/myName/ex2/all'):
            if filename.startswith('H2O'):
                filename = 'H2O.r{}theta{}.out'.format(i,j)                
                E[i,j] = extract(filename)
```

Comment: If I see this correctly, `r_2dp` is a string array; when you later loop through it and set `E[i, j]`, `i` is a string which probably is the cause of the error you get.

Comment: Hi, I understand why the error comes up, I just don't know how I can avoid it. I need `r_2dp` to be a string array so that the `filename = ...` works. I don't know how to do this otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to associate an index with the filename which you can accomplish using `enumerate`; I think you can just change your loop to

```
for i, fn in enumerate(r_2dp):
    for j, ti in enumerate(theta):
        for filename in os.listdir('C:/Users/myName/ex2/all'):
            if filename.startswith('H2O'):
                filename = 'H2O.r{}theta{}.out'.format(fn,ti)                
                E[j,i] = extract(filename)
```

Please note that I changed `E[i,j]` to `E[j,i]` to get the dimensions correctly; you could also change the order of the two for-loops or initialize `E` the other way round...

Untested, as we cannot access your file, but the general idea should work...

Comment: Hi, this works if I enumerate for theta too, as this was a list of floats. But now I think there is a problem with the array size I am trying to fit these data values in to: `IndexError: index 25 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 25` . If I print `E`, some of the elements are populated with the right-looking values, but most are still 0

Comment: @loolipop: True, you also need `enumerate` for `theta`. To get rid of this error, either use `E[j, i]` or change the order of your loops for `r_2dp` and `theta` or initialze `E` the other way round. Again, untested.

Comment: Yep thankyou ! I also needed to remove the `for filename in os.listdir...` line as I was already in this directory, and this with the `.format(fn,ti)` meant that an infinite number of `filename` kept on being generated